# What is the difference between 'until now' and 'ever since'?

Tags: word-choice

- Hello,everyone. *
  could you help me ?
  I know both mean from a past time till now but my question is could they be used interchangeably? If no, please mention why ?
  Tnx in advance.

Answer (score 1):

They are not interchangeable. One simple reason is that "ever since" implies the "starting point" - since what point in the past? While "until now" only specifies the "end point" - now.

Hope this helps.

Comment: so the difference refers to their emphasis on the particular time of the period ' from a starting point till now ' , in which the former focuses on end point and the latter on starting point of the time period.

Comment: Isn't that ? ...

Comment: My answer is focused on the fact that the two are not interchangeable. The actual difference is, in fact, much broader than the single reason I mentioned. I'd suggest you do your own research by trying 'until now meaning' and 'ever since meaning' in google search. Also, you could use some online translating tool and translate these two expessions into your native language - this might help to grasp the difference.